# How do I take my badges out and look at them?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

I was polishing my badges and for some reason one of them popped out for me to look at and rotate. I tried a bunch of different things but was unable to do it again.

What do I need to do on the badge screen to pull the badges out of the badge case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending too much time trying to get it to work, I found out that if you very carefully press and hold on a badge it will pop out. If you move even a little bit it will start polishing the badge, so you need to be very steady when pressing on it.

Comment: ok I was just waiting to see if someone else had a more reliable way to get them out

Comment: also I cannot accept the answer until tomorrow