# Is it possible to take the badges out to look at them?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum, pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

In the remakes you can [pull badges out and rotate them around to look at them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392664/how-do-i-take-my-badges-out-and-look-at-them).

Is that a new feature for the remake, or can you do the same thing in the original DS versions?